# Prevent AWS Lambda throttling from async invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm currently modeling a serverless application that extensively uses S3 events as a source for lambda functions.

I've configured the Dead-Letter Queue (DLQ) for lambda to provide some resilience, but I'm still wondering: is there any other way to reduce lambda concurrency and prevent the throttling issue?

Theoretically, AWS docs state that for the asynchronous invocation, Lambda uses the internal queue to process events and retries, which means that there should be no problem for Lambda to process this queue without throttling.

In a non-serverless app, I would organize it with a queue and a limited number of queue workers, however, this is not that trivial for AWS.

Are there any other ways except the DLQ, to handle or avoid the throttling issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, plugging a Lambda directly to S3 events gives many issues, including throttling and message loss.

How we (on production) usually do is to push all the S3 events to an SQS and have the Lambda function be triggered from that (not polling). Then you have more control over the parallel executions, retries, and retention.

You can use SNS instead of SQS, but I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: And how do you configure your Lambda triggers for SQS? Just using the standard built-in SQS->Lambda trigger option, or scheduling Lambda with CloudWatch for polling?

Comment: It's a usual SQS --> Lambda trigger. Not polling.